# How to compare a value against a lookup table in an ember template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

The idea is to be able to perform something similar to this:

```
{{ #each color in colors }}
   <li class="{{if car.color==color 'selected' " > </li>
{{/each}}
```

I am aware of the fact that ember's policy is not to have logic in the templates, still, this (simple) problem is not answered to me, after a day's search.

Comment: Look into class name bindings. They're quite powerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a component, add the logic into a component as a computed property.

A really boring example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/conijumego/1/edit

You can also use `needs` and an `itemController`.

Another boring example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/taluwuquli/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score -1):

Use classNameBindings on an Ember Component:

> "If the bound property's value is a string, that value will be added
>   as a class name without modification"
>   [Ember Component Docs](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/components/customizing-a-components-element/)

[Working JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/zusiti/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

In the demo I am defining the value for the class name for the component within the template, but as you can see in the component js, the value could come from anywhere ie., Model data, an array declared in the component etc. No need for an item controller. That approach is being deprecated anyway. We are advised to stay away from controllers in order to have a clear upgrade path to Ember 2.0